# ArrayList<ModelClass> list inside one Arraylist - in Adapter

Tags: android

So, I have a Model class which stores some data (Model{id, name} al).then have another model class1 which contain a list of class such as(Arraylist list). I want to set it in adapter eg(list.add(al)), then I want to set list to the adapter. I know how to set an adapter. but the problem is every time while adding to the adapter it creates a new ArrayList.bellow I attach an image.[image]

Comment: Please post the code snippet. Reading your code from photo is really hard

Comment: public class FilterModel {
    private int Id;
    private ArrayList<HierarchieModel> list;

    public FilterModel(int id, ArrayList<HierarchieModel> list) {
        Id = id;
        this.list = list;
    }

   

    public ArrayList<HierarchieModel> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}

Comment: This istill unreadable you can make use of 

"``` ````" to post some code snippet

Also updating the question with the code snippet will help others as they might not read the comments

Comment: you don't need to set the adapter again and again to update your list. just update your list and called `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`